# Unterminated object at character 10 of

Tags: android, json

i know this question has been asked many times but I couldn`t find any solution for this one...
in android 5.1 work perfectly but under api level 21 give me this error:
sorry for my bad english...

```
12-12 05:00:36.155: E/ads(20330): org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 10 of {dat=2015/12/3, titlecolor=008000, icon=err, des=با سلام. این پیام تنها برای تست کارکرد درون برنامه ای سامانه دی جی ادروید میباشد, title=تست درون برنامه ای دیجی ادروید, matncolor=000000, link=http://digiadroid.ir, pname=com.digiadroid.ad, openimm=0, shenase=aFrR0hKTY01vUvf, backcolor=FFFF99, mode=1}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) requires all strings values (and property names) to be surrounded by double-quotes. Some JSON parsers may be more lax than others, but the best policy is always to generate JSON data that strictly conforms to the official syntax.

If you are not the one generating the data, then you need to have the party responsible fix their code.